# Websocket without command line?

Tags: php, websocket

I am trying to modify web socket app in [this tutorial](https://www.flynsarmy.com/2012/02/php-websocket-chat-application-2-0/).
I need to start and stop server using web interface without using command prompt. How to do it?
I used exec() and system() commands. but was not successfull

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about passing some specific messages to start/stop service. The idea is to have service working non-stop, but when service detects "stop" message it will stop answering on any other messages except "start" message.